# Repositioning ImageView Programmatically Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

In my application, I have an activity that loads an image into an ImageView positioned in the center of the screen. The image is first scaled to fit on the screen, and then after the bitmap of the ImageView is set, the ImageView is then resized to the same size as the Bitmap.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) galleryActivity.findViewById(R.id.selectedImage);
Bitmap image = fileList.get(displayedImageIndex).loadScaledImage();
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = image.getWidth();
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = image.getHeight();
imageView.requestLayout();
```

The problem is, after the ImageView is resized, it is no longer centered in the middle of the screen, it is aligned to the top of its parent. I tried both imageView.setY and imageView.setTranslationY to try and move it back to the center, but neither of those re-positioned the View. Is there any way to keep the ImageView aligned in the center of the parent after it is resized?

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="toggleActionBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout.  You can definitely get it centered, but how you're using it changes the best way to do so.  But its probably gravity or layout_gravity that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)        
galleryActivity.findViewById(R.id.selectedImage);   
Bitmap image = fileList.get(displayedImageIndex).loadScaledImage();
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
int cxScreen;  // you must fill it
int cyScreen;  // this to
int cxImg = imageView.getWidth(); // change image to imageView
int cyImg = imageView.getHeight(); // as up

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(cxImg, cyImg);
lp.leftMargin = (cxScreen-cxImg)/2;
lp.topMargin  = (cyScreen-cyImg)/2; // change something to cyScreen
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**EDIT** change 3 lines

```
Log.i("TAG", "cxS:"+cxScreen.toString()+", cyS:"+cyScreen.toString());
Log.i("TAG", "image:"+imageView.toString());
Log.i("TAG", "parent:"+(imageView.getParent()).toString());
```

Comment: That would work, but its a little complicated.  Setting the gravity in the layout is a lot easier.

Comment: its most simply solution, nothing to do with layout and gravity

Comment: No, its not.  You're doing a lot of calculation, and you have 2 parts you didn't even know how to fill out.  Or you can set the correct gravity in the layout, and do 0 calculations.

Comment: In this flexible solution image may be dynammicaly moved to every position on the screen, in this case - center.

Comment: @skippy I tried this solution, and it didn't work, it aligned the center of the ImageView to the top right corner of the screen

Comment: @GabeSechan I added gravity to the parent layout, no change

Comment: @Thomas, see changes

Comment: @skippy I implemented the changes and there was no change in behavior, the center of the ImageView is still aligned to the top right corner

Comment: @Thomas please log it, like in my answer after imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Comment: This will crop the bitmap to be centered but will not adjust width and height